# How to get accurate age(including year and months) from current date?

Tags: android, methods, datepicker, monthcalendar

I want to find the exact age not just in years but should get exact months also.
ie current date:18-05-2015, the date i want to test is 01-01-2010-Output should be
4years 8 months.

```
public float getAge (int _year, int _month, int _day) {

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int y, m, d,a,b;
    //float ans = 0;         
    y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
    a = y - (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
   // b=m-(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                    || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (d < cal
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
            --a;
    }
    if(a < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");

    ans=a;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Calculate the date difference in months. Then use an integer division by 12. Then perform a modulo. The result of the division is the years. The rest (result of the modulo) is the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Joda time**.It is best to calculate date differences.[Download](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) **joda-time.jar** and paste it in libs.

Then use the following code:

```
public static String getTimestampDiff() {
        final DateTime start = new DateTime(datefrom.getTime());
        final DateTime end = new DateTime(dateto.getTime());
        Period p = new Period(start, end);
        PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendYears()
        .appendSuffix(" year", " years").appendSeparator(", ")
        .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months").toFormatter();
        /* .appendSeparator(", ").appendDays()
                        .appendSuffix(" day", " days").appendSeparator(" and ")
                        .appendHours().appendLiteral(":").appendMinutes()
                        .appendLiteral(":").appendSeconds().toFormatter();*/
        return p.toString(formatter);
    }
```

You should declare datefrom and dateto as reference of Date class like: `static Date datefrom,dateto;` and form the datefrom object like:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            datepickeryear  = selectedYear;
            datepickermonth = selectedMonth;
            datepickerday   = selectedDay;
            // Show selected date
            edfromdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(datepickeryear)
                    .append("-").append(datepickermonth + 1)
                    .append("-").append(datepickerday).append(" "));

            datefrom =new Date(datepickeryear, datepickermonth+1, datepickerday);

        }
    };
```

Here I have used a datepicker,**but you can form a Date object of your own**.